# Mysql query in activerecord in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have following mysql query that I need to use in yii2 -

```
select tsell.district,tsell.totalsale as sell,coalesce(tcollection.collection,0) as collection from(SELECT district, coalesce(sell.sale,0) as totalsale FROM `districts` left join (SELECT parties_district, billdate,sum(billamount) as sale FROM `bills` left join parties on bills.bills_partyname = parties.parties_partyname group by parties_district) as sell on sell.parties_district = districts.district) as tsell left join (SELECT parties_district,payment_date,COALESCE(sum(payment_amount),0) as collection FROM `payment` left join parties on payment.payment_partyname = parties.parties_partyname group by parties_district) as tcollection on tsell.district = tcollection.parties_district
```

My search model is

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\districtreport\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use frontend\modules\districtreport\models\Parties;
use frontend\modules\districtreport\models\Bills;
use frontend\modules\districtreport\models\Payment;
use yii\db\Query;
use yii\db\Command;
$query = \Yii::$app->db;
/**
 * PartiesSearch represents the model behind the search form about `frontend\modules\districtreport\models\Parties`.
 */
class PartiesSearch extends Parties
{
    public $bills;
    public $district;
    public $sale;
    public $sell;
    public $collection;
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['party_id'], 'integer'],
            [['parties_partyname', 'address', 'parties_district', 'name_manager', 'transport', 'dlno', 'instruction', 'con', 'district','sale','sell','collection'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {

        $sql = 'select tsell.district,tsell.totalsale as sell,coalesce(tcollection.collection,0) as collection from(SELECT district, coalesce(sell.sale,0) as totalsale FROM `districts` left join (SELECT parties_district, billdate,sum(billamount) as sale FROM `bills` left join parties on bills.bills_partyname = parties.parties_partyname group by parties_district) as sell on sell.parties_district = districts.district) as tsell left join (SELECT parties_district,payment_date,COALESCE(sum(payment_amount),0) as collection FROM `payment` left join parties on payment.payment_partyname = parties.parties_partyname group by parties_district) as tcollection on tsell.district = tcollection.parties_district';
        $query = Parties::findBySql($sql);

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            //'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['district'=>SORT_DESC]]
        ]);

        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['sell'] = [
        // The tables are the ones our relation are configured to
        // in my case they are prefixed with "tbl_"
        'asc' => ['tsell.sell' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['tsell.sell' => SORT_DESC],
        ];

        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['collection'] = [
        // The tables are the ones our relation are configured to
        // in my case they are prefixed with "tbl_"
        'asc' => ['collection' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['collection' => SORT_DESC],
        ];
        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['district'] = [
        // The tables are the ones our relation are configured to
        // in my case they are prefixed with "tbl_"
        'asc' => ['tsell.district' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['tsell.district' => SORT_DESC],
        ];


        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'party_id' => $this->party_id,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'parties_partyname', $this->parties_partyname])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'address', $this->address])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'parties_district', $this->parties_district])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name_manager', $this->name_manager])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'transport', $this->transport])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'dlno', $this->dlno])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'instruction', $this->instruction])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'con', $this->con])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'sell', $this->sell])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'collection', $this->collection])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'district', $this->district]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

But the problem is that I am unable to sort or filter the columns. So I want to use activerecord to run the query instead of findbysql. Please help me  to build this query in activerecord.

My index.php file looks like -

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
//use kartik\widgets\DatePicker;
use kartik\daterange\DateRangePicker;
use kartik\form\ActiveForm;
use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\modules\districtreport\models\PartiesSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Parties';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="parties-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

<!--     <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Parties', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p> -->
    <!-- <div class="custom-filter">

    Date range:
     <input name="start" />
     <input name="end" />

    </div> -->


        <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],


            'district',           
            'sell',
            'collection',


            //['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

Here's my PartiesController.php

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\districtreport\controllers;

use Yii;
use frontend\modules\districtreport\models\Parties;
use frontend\modules\districtreport\models\PartiesSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * PartiesController implements the CRUD actions for Parties model.
 */
class PartiesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Parties models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new PartiesSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Parties model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Parties model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Parties();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->party_id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Parties model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->party_id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Parties model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Parties model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Parties the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Parties::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do yoy mean a i want use activeRecord .? . the activeRecord are meanly base on table you use a temporary table  .. and in this case the findBySql seems the  right chioce  ... And last the sort and filter are related to the dataProvider indipendently if you use find() or findBySql ..

Comment: All I want is to filter and sort the data by district, sell and collection.

Comment: Have you tried my answer for sort ? .. work? .. don't work? .. error ?

Comment: Yes I've tried. But it's not sorting

Comment: please show your gridview (view) code ..

Comment: I've added the view file in the question.

Comment: You see the filter field above the column ?

Comment: yes. I see the filter field above the column.

Comment: Show also the related action please ..

Comment: I've added the controller code in the question.

Comment: This code seems allright.. In the model  you have not defined the calculated columns $bills, $district, $sale, $sell, $collection right?

Comment: I've added $district, $sale, $sell, $collection in the parties model. But not the $bills. Is it required?

Answer (score 0):

Pls have a [look](https://www.sitepoint.com/rendering-data-in-yii-2-with-gridview-and-listview/)

```
$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
    'sql' => 'SELECT Name, Title, COUNT(ArticleTags.ID) AS TagCount ' . 
             'FROM Authors ' .
             'INNER JOIN Articles ON (Authors.ID = Articles.AuthorID) ' .
             'INNER JOIN ArticleTags ON (Articles.ID = ArticleTags.ID) ' .
             'WHERE Name=:author' .
             'GROUP BY ArticleID',
    'params' => [':author' => 'Arno Slatius'],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In query you missing a district alias

```
    select 
        tsell.district as district,
        tsell.totalsale as sell,
        coalesce(tcollection.collection,0) as collection 
        from 
            (SELECT 
                district, 
                coalesce(sell.sale,0) as totalsale 
            FROM `districts` 
            left join 
                (SELECT 
                    parties_district, 
                    billdate,
                    sum(billamount) as sale 
                FROM `bills` 
                left join parties on bills.bills_partyname = parties.parties_partyname 
                group by parties_district) as sell 
            on sell.parties_district = districts.district) as tsell 
        left join 
            (SELECT 
                parties_district,
                payment_date,
                COALESCE(sum(payment_amount),0) as collection 
            FROM `payment` 
            left join parties on payment.payment_partyname = parties.parties_partyname 
            group by parties_district) as tcollection 
               on tsell.district = tcollection.parties_district
```

For sort i suggest you this notation

```
    $dataProvider->setSort([
            'attributes' => [
                'sell' => [
                   'asc' => ['tsell.sell' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => ['tsell.sell' => SORT_DESC],
                    'label' => 'Sell'
                ],
                'collection' => [
                    'asc' => ['collection' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => ['collection' => SORT_DESC],      
                    'label' => 'Collection'
                ]      
                'district' => [
                    'asc' => ['tsell.district' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => ['tsell.district' => SORT_DESC],
                    'label' => 'District'
                ]                               
            ]
        ]);
```

Be sure you have declare the vars    `$bills, $district, $sale, $sell, $collection`   only in one model class.
If you use these vars in several extended searchModel then declare only in model
otherwise declare only in the searhModel ..

Never declare in both the same var one override the others and mismatch when used by model or modelSearch function ..

Comment: My question is how can I write this query in ActiveDataProvider like - 'query' => Articles::find()->with('author')->where(['Name'=>'Arno Slatius']),.... Also I'm unable to sort or filter the data

Comment: I've added these vars only in Parties model and removed it from PartiesSearch model. But still unable to sort or filter. Please help. Please tell how to filter it. Because I have added kartik expandrow in it. The filter column is passing the district to the second level but it's not filtering. Please help.